# Does Parse.com permit the inclusion of pointers inside a relation query?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the following many-to-many relationship in my Parse.com application:

Bit ↔ Message

The following fetches related messages from a 'Bit' object:

```
const query = new Parse.Query('Bit');
query.include('participants');
query.include('user');
query.equalTo('objectId', req.query.bitId);
const promise = query.first().then(function(bit) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    const relation = bit.relation('messages');
    relation.query().find().then(function(messages) {
      resolve(messages);
    });
  });
});
```

*Note: messages is a relation column type *not* a pointer type.

The result inside `messages` is an array that contains all of the related messages for that bit. Each message contains a pointer to a User called `sender`. Is it possible to include this User object in the query result? It would be nice if I could use the `include()` method on a relational query like so:

```
relation.include('sender');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can qualify a relation's query as you would any other query.  (Also, you've got some superfluous promise code in the OP.  I cleaned that up a little, but the point of the answer is on the commented line)...

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Bit');
query.include('participants');
query.include('user');
query.equalTo('objectId', req.query.bitId);
var promise = query.first().then(function(bit) {
    var relationalQuery = bit.relation('messages').query();
    relationalQuery.include("sender");  // <-- the point
    return relationalQuery().find();
}).then(function(messages) {
    return resolve(messages);
});
```